# Prove that all whole numbers that are at the same time a square and a cube have the form $7k$ or $7k+1$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Given the following problem:

> Applying the division algorithm, prove that all whole numbers that are at the same time a square and a cube have the form $7k$ or $7k+1$.

I am unable to interpret what it is asking of me and therefore I am unable to provide any solutions. Could someone explain to me what exactly the problem is asking and how do I solve it?

Comment: Basically it's asking you to prove that $a^6\equiv0$ or $1\pmod7$ whenever $a$ is an integer.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown:  I agree that is what we are supposed to prove, but I don't see how one is supposed to use the division algorithm.  I would just take all the residue classes $\pmod 7$ and try them.

Comment: It is by the division algorithm that we know that $a^6=7k+r$ for some integers $k$ and $0\leq r\leq 6$.

Comment: What it is asking is:  Prove that if $M = a^2 = b^3$ where $a, b$ are integers, then prove either $M = 7k$ for some integer $k$ or that $M = 7k + 1$ for some integer.

Comment: @RossMillikan  Wouldn't you say "the division algorithm" is nothing more or less than the statement all integers belong to a residue class? So if you check the residue classes you check all integers.

Comment: I'm wondering are we to assume the student knows anything.  Even that $M =a^2 = b^3$ means that $M$ is 6-power.  We can use the remainder theorem to show that $a^2$ will have remainder $0,1,4,2,2,4,1$ if $a$ has remainder $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ and that $b^3$ will have remainder $0,1,1,6,1,6,6$ if $b$ has remainder of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$.  As $a^2 = b^3$ then it most have remainder $0,1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering are we to assume the student knows anything.  Even that $M =a^2 = b^3$ means that $M$ is 6-power.

We can use the remainder theorem to show that $a^2$ will have remainder $0,1,4,2,2,4,1$ if $a$ has remainder $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$

That is $a = 7m + k$ so $a^2 = 49m^2 + 14mk +k^2$ so $a^2$ will have the same remainder as $k^2$.  And we can calculate those to be $0,1,4,2,2,4,1$.

And we can see that $b^3$ will have remainder $0,1,1,6,1,6,6$ if $b$ has remainder of $0,1,2,3,4,5,6$.

If $b = 7n+j$ then $b^3 = 7^3n^3 + 3*7^2n^2j + 3*7nj^2 + j^3$ so $b^3$ will have the same remainder as $j^3$ and we calculate those to be $0,1,1,6,1,6,6$.

As $a^2 = b^3$ then it must have remainder $0,1$.

====== full answer =====

If $M = a^2=b^3$ where $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers then $M = c^6$ for some integer $c$.  (Because the prime factors of $M$ must be the prime factors of $b$ and $a$ and must as they divide $a^2$ must be to an even power and as they divide $b^3$ must be to a third power, so they must be to a multiple of $6$ power.)

So $M = c^6$.

No by division algorithm there are unique integers $n,j$ so that $c = 7n + j$ and $0 \le j < 7$.

$(7n + j)^6 = 7^6n^6 + a*7^5n^5*j + b*7^4n^4*j^2 + ... + e7n*j^5 + j^6$ where $a,b,c ....$ are the binomial coefficients.

$7^6n^6 + a*7^5n^5*j + b*7^4n^4*j^2 + ... + e7n*j^5 = 7K$ for an integer $K$ so

$M = 7K + j^6$ where $j = 0,1,....,6$.

$0^6 = 0 = 7*0$.

$1^6 = 1 = 7*0 + 1$

$2^6 = 64 = 7*9 + 1$

$3^6 = 27^2 = (4*7 - 1)^2 = 16*7^2 - 8*7 + 1 = 7(16*7 -8) + 1$

And $4,5,6 = (7-3),(7-2),(7-1)$ and $(7 - k)^6 = 7^6 - a7^5k + b7^4k^2 -.... - e7*k^6 + k^6$.

And as $k^6 = 7m +1 $ for some $m$ $4^6,5^6,6^6$ also equal $7j + 1$ for some integer $j$.

So $M = c^6 = 7K + j^6$.  If $j=0$ that is $M = 7K$.  If  $j=1...6$ then $j^6 = 7m + 1$ for some $m$ and $M = 7(K+m) + 1$.

.... And all of that should incentive enough to learn modulo notation to make the whole thing four lines.

$c^6 \equiv 0 \mod 7$ if $c \equiv 0 \mod 7$

$(\pm 1)^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$

$(\pm 2)^6 \equiv 64 \equiv 1 \mod 7$

$(\pm 3)^6 \equiv 9^3 \equiv 2^3 \equiv 8 \equiv 1 \mod 7$

So $c^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ if $c \not \equiv 0 \mod 7$.

======

Then there is Fermat's Little Theorem:

$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ if $a \not \equiv 0 \mod p$ and $p$ is prime.

So $a^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7$ if $a\not \equiv 0\mod p$ and $a^6\equiv 0\mod 7$ if $a \equiv 0 \mod 7$.

($1$ line.)

Answer (score 2):

we have $$x\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6\mod 7$$ then
$$x^6\equiv 0,1,1,1,1,1,1 \mod 7$$ you should check this

Comment: I don't grasp your concept. Could you explain it a bit?

Comment: put each number $^6$ and compute the remainder mod $6$

Comment: examble $$6^6=46656\equiv 1 \mod 7$$